# Windows 10 mute/unmute fades-out/in instead of muting abruptly

Tags: windows-10, mute

How can I make it mute instantaneously like it's supposed to? I can't find a setting, and any kind of search is overshadowed with results for troubleshooting completely different problems.

Comment: Are you using the Keyboard Shortcut (best) or the System Tray (works),  Either way to mute is instant.  No issue - tested on two computers.  How are you muting?

Comment: @John I'm using the mute button on my keyboard. The mute seems to fade-out/in over ~1000ms. However, the same is true if I click the mute button for me output device on the sound mixer.

Comment: I an getting instant results on my two laptops.  Can you try another keyboard in case that is the issue.  Is the Sound Mixer causing this?

Comment: I don't have another keyboard, however, I figured-out that it's this stupid usb device I have that gives me another 3.5mm jack. I have no idea why it does this, it doesn't have it's own special drivers or software -.-

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to some dubious aspect of [this device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N905VOY). This has no special drivers or software (it's totally plug-and-play) and I can't find any setting anywhere that anything to do with this.

The issue was bypassed by simply using a different output device.